Cambiar parte de pagina html con radio buttom
recientemente estoy ingresando a la programación, y requiero realizar una operación que no encuentro la solución. Estoy haciendo una aplicación en PHP.
Lo que requiero es que al elegir una opción de unos radio buttom (cliente o proveedor),cambie una parte del html para que muestre un botón que listará los clientes o proveedores según sea el caso. Por defecto esta en 'cliente'. El código es el siguiente:
 <div>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo_guia" id="cliente" value="cliente" " onChange="comprobar()" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="cliente">Cliente</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo_guia" id="proveedor" value="proveedor" onChange="comprobar()">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="proveedor">Proveedor</label>
</div>

<div>
    <?php  if(empty($_SESSION['tipo'] || $_SESSION['tipo']=="cliente")){?>
    <span>Seleccione un cliente</span>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <span>Seleccione un proveedor</span>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

Lo que se me ocurría es setear con variables de estado, con ello refrescar la página y que muestre las opciones correctas. Pero la verdad de javascript no se mucho, y no se como poder conectar ese evento onChange para que defina la variable.
Si me pudieran echar una mano.
gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Tampoco necesitas javascript, solo un poco de CSS:


.seleccion{
  display:none;
}

body:has(#cliente:checked) #seleccionCliente{
 display:unset;
}

body:has(#proveedor:checked) #seleccionProveedor{
 display:unset;
}
<div>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo_guia" id="cliente" value="cliente" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="cliente">Cliente</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo_guia" id="proveedor" value="proveedor">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="proveedor">Proveedor</label>
</div>

<div>

  <div class="seleccion" id="seleccionCliente">
    <span>Seleccione un cliente</span>
  </div>
  <div class="seleccion" id="seleccionProveedor">
    <span>Seleccione un proveedor</span>
  </div>
</div>



